# SQL Server naming of columns of ConstantScan operator for UNPIVOT statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a table named pvt:

```
CREATE TABLE pvt (
 VendorID int, 
 Emp1 int, 
 Emp2 int
);
GO
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (1,4,3);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (2,4,1);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (3,4,3);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (4,4,2);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (5,5,1);
GO
```

Now I perform the following query:

```
SELECT VendorID, 
Employee + 'x', 
Orders + 10
FROM pvt
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2)
)AS unpvt;
GO
```

If I look into XML query plan I found the following ConstantScan operator:

```
<RelOp AvgRowSize="143" EstimateCPU="2.157E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="3.78349" EstimateRewinds="0.21651" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="2" LogicalOp="Constant Scan" NodeId="8" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Constant Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.0157E-05">
<OutputList>
    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
</OutputList>
<ConstantScan>
    <Values>
        <Row>
        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="N'Emp1'">
            <Const ConstValue="N'Emp1'" />
        </ScalarOperator>
        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[MyDB].[dbo].[pvt].[Emp1]">
            <Identifier>
            <ColumnReference Database="[MyDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pvt]" Column="Emp1" />
            </Identifier>
        </ScalarOperator>
        </Row>
        <Row>
        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="N'Emp2'">
            <Const ConstValue="N'Emp2'" />
        </ScalarOperator>
        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[MyDB].[dbo].[pvt].[Emp2]">
            <Identifier>
            <ColumnReference Database="[MyDB]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[pvt]" Column="Emp2" />
            </Identifier>
        </ScalarOperator>
        </Row>
    </Values>
</ConstantScan>
```

Therefore, the ConstantScan operator create a table where the first column has value 'Emp1' or 'Emp2' and the second column is retrieved from the pvt table. From the OutputList element of this operator it seems that the first column has name 'Expr1006' and the second one 'Expr1007' (assuming that they are in the same order as columns each row). However, if I look on the computations in the query it is the other way arround (Expr1007 is the first column that contains the EmpX values). My question is: how ConstantScan maps the Expr names to its columns?